# installing openCV inside intelliJidea to develop an android app

Tags: android, opencv, intellij-idea

I want to use openCV in my android applications but I couldn’t find a way to add opencv libraries in intellij Idea and use them. any clue?

Comment: go to VM options and add

Comment: See [this document](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).